# Reading & Interacting With HTML Table Using Python

Tags: python, html, pandas, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to web scrape information from an HTML table that has interactive ability to sift through various time periods. An example table is located at this URL: http://quotes.freerealtime.com/dl/frt/M?IM=quotes&type=Time%26Sales&SA=quotes&symbol=IBM&qm_page=45750.

I'd like to start at the time of 9:30 and then interact with the table by jumping forward 1 min. I want to export all of the data to a DataFrame.
I've tried using pandas.read_html() and also tried using BeautifulSoup. Neither of these are working for me albeit I am inexperienced with BeautifulSoup. Is my request possible or has the website protected this information from web scraping? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Are you interested in selenium-specific approach?

Comment: Yes definitely!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The page is quite dynamic (and terribly slow, at least on my side), involves JavaScript and multiple asynchronous requests to get the data. Approaching that with `requests` would not be easy and you might need to fall into using browser automation via, for example, `selenium`.

Here is something for you to get started. Note the use of [Explicit Waits](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits) here and there:

```
import pandas as pd
import time

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("http://quotes.freerealtime.com/dl/frt/M?IM=quotes&type=Time%26Sales&SA=quotes&symbol=IBM&qm_page=45750")

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 400)  # 400 seconds timeout

# wait for select element to be visible
time_select = Select(wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "select[name=time]"))))

# select 9:30 and go
time_select.select_by_visible_text("09:30")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", driver.find_element_by_id("go"))
time.sleep(2)

while True:
    # wait for the table to appear and load to pandas dataframe
    table = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "qmmt-time-and-sales-data-table")))
    df = pd.read_html(table.get_attribute("outerHTML"))
    print(df[0])

    # wait for offset select to be visible and forward it 1 min
    offset_select = Select(wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "select[name=timeOffset]"))))
    offset_select.select_by_value("1")

    time.sleep(2)

    # TODO: think of a break condition
```

Note that this works really, really slow on my machine and I am not sure how well it would run on yours, but it continuously advances 1 minute forward in an endless loop (you would probably need to stop it at some point).

Comment: Thank you! I am having an error while running this. Message: 'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH

Comment: @Evy555 yeah, that's a [common problem with current selenium/firefox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40208051/selenium-using-python-geckodriver-executable-needs-to-be-in-path).

Answer (score 0):

This page is rendered by JavaScript, if you disable the JS in your browser, the output of this page is:

[image]

requests or pandas only handle the HTML code.

Comment: So am I not able to access the information because it's rendered in JavaScript?

Comment: @Evy555 yes, use selenium if you want to interact with browser.